# Angular: How to parse template and return HTML

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, swiper.js

I'm struggling with something. I'm using ion-slides to render a set of slides as follows:

```
<ion-slides options="vm.sliderOptions" slider="data.slider">
    <ion-slide-page ng-repeat="notification in vm.subsetNotifications" >
        <span ng-include="'notificationSlide.html'"></span>
    </ion-slide-page>
</ion-slides>
```

This is working fine.

However, I want to dynamically add slides to the end using the Swiper API:

```
vm.slider.appendSlide(HTML);
```

if I just use plain HTML in the appendSlide, it works fine.

However, I want to parse the template notificationSlide.html with a new set of data currently held in the controller.

Any pointers on how I can do that please?

Regards,
Andyy

Comment: You can push your new slides to `subsetNotifications.push(newSlide);`

Comment: @Blakey UK did you find a solution to this? I have been facing the same problem.

Comment: Hi DazzleR. Sorry for the late reply - no. I just moved the slides out of scope after a lot of pain trying to get it to work in various ways.